# Rest API Basic Authentication

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

Is it okay if the server returns the API Key and Shared Secret Key when a client tries to login on the API using Basic Authentication? For example, if a user enter this link http://api.example.com/authorize?auth=some_encoded_Base64_string, the response will be:

```
Content-Type: application/xml
Date: Fri, 10 Nov 2006 20:04:45 GMT    
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Authorization: apiKey;secretKey
```

Will I have issues using this method? I wanted to be like this since the API core methods will only accept APIKey hashes and in order to obtain that they need to use the Basic Authentication as they're first step. I'm not gonna use OAuth here for now.

I'm trying out the new ASP.NET Web API for this project.

Comment: It looks fine, as long as the whole communication is over HTTPS.

Comment: I think it is fine. FogBugz, for example, has a method which works exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was looking for an public API using this but didn't found. I'll go take a look at FogBugz how they're implementing it.

Comment: Additional question, should I use the header in passing the username and password of the client or pass it on the URI and return the token on the header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP does not define an `Authorization` header in the response so if you need to define a custom header, use `X-` prefix.

Also from the design point, HTTP headers are to pass data which is *orthogonal* to the call. You seem to be trying to pass a piece of data which needs to be in the payload so I would refrain from using the headers.

I would pass this data in the payload.

If you use SSL and pass data in the URL, HTTP headers or payload it will be secure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to digest what you have said but I don't seem to get what payload means? What I mean by the authorization is I'll be using the HTTP Authorization header.

Comment: payload I mean part of the data that you send back. HTTP Authorization header is fine for request but not response.

Comment: okay I got it. Where should I put the server response? On the URI?